# Is Zephyr One really the "biggest plane ever built" in Agents of S.H.IE.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season 4 episode 1, Piper says to a group of STRIKE operatives:

> PIPER: Okay, people! What, you never seen the biggest plane ever built before?

This is in reference to Zephyr One, Coulson's new plane. The Wiki (which is not necessarily canon) says that the Zephyr is 280 feet long. The Antonov An-225 Mriya, largely considered to be the largest plane built, was 275 feet 7 inches long and 290 feet in wingspan. So is the Zephyr One the "biggest plane ever built"? Do we have canon information on the specifications of the plane?

Comment: "*The Zephyr is 280 feet long, it's almost a football field in length,*" Kolpack told Ars - https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2020/08/agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-takes-final-bow-with-high-octane-journey-through-time/

Comment: The real question is, how do you define "biggest"? For example, by wingspan, both Roc and the Spruce Goose are actually bigger than the An-225. OTOH, the An-225 is the longest aircraft, longer than a B747-8.